# Draw overlay over multiple monitors

Tags: java, swt, desktop-application

I'd like to draw overlay over multiple monitors, it should cover every taskbar, basically every element. I use SWT in version 4.5.2.

What I have done so far?

```
shell = new Shell(display.getActiveShell(), SWT.ON_TOP | SWT.DOUBLE_BUFFERED);
shell.setBounds(display.getBounds());
```

This solution works perfectly on my Debian (stretch).
There're troubles with windows, I have tested windows 10 and it draws overlay however taskbars are on the top.

I think about N separated shells with activated fullscreen on N monitors, but I don't think it's possible to activate fullscreen on more than one shell.

Does anybody have any idea? Maybe I should try to use other library?

Answer (score 1):

Total spitball, but

```
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0);
Stream.of(shell.getDisplay().getMonitors()).map(Monitor::getBounds).forEach(p->rect.add(p));
shell.setBounds(rect);
```

Comment: my problem is not bounds of displays, because it draws overlay but taskbars on win10 covers it :/ I don't know if it's limitation of swt or windows, anyway thank you for trying to help

Comment: `Display d = Display.getDefault();
  final Shell s1 = new Shell(Display.getCurrent(), SWT.ON_TOP | SWT.DOUBLE_BUFFERED);
  s1.setBounds(d.getBounds());
  s1.setLayout(new FillLayout());
  Button b = new Button(s1, SWT.NONE);
  b.setText("getBounds()");
  b.addListener(SWT.Selection, e -> {
   s1.dispose();
  });
  s1.open();
  while (!s1.isDisposed()) {
   if (!d.readAndDispatch()) {
    d.sleep();
   }
  }`

This works on Windows 7 running 64-bit JRE 1.8.0_77.

Covers the whole screen, task bar included

Comment: @pretzalcoatl OPs original solution works fine on Windows 7 as well. Windows 10 seems to be the problem here.

Comment: @Baz both calling `display.getBounds()` directly or accumulating `Monitor.getBounds()` work fine on a single monitor on Windows 10.  Odd.